# Subtract Vertical Offset to Document Fragment scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a fixed header and I want a url like `http://example.com#foo` to scroll to the element with `id=foo` and subtract the height of the header so that the element is visible.

I've tried the following, but in at least Chrome, this code is run before the default document fragment scrolling occurs so the scroll position is overwritten:

```
$(function() {
  var offset;
  if (window.location.hash !== "") {
     offset = $(window.location.hash).offset().top;
     return $("body").scrollTop(offset - headerHeight);
  }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/rk8y7/1/

Comment: Are you able to see the element with normal scrolling? Cannot see problem here otherwise http://jsfiddle.net/rk8y7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by changing the `id` of the DOM element to be the current id + `_section` and then listening for a `hashchange` event to set the scroll position of the page. 
I also had to trigger `hashchange` on pageload to get it to the work on the first page load.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var elemId, headerHeight, offset;
    elemId = window.location.hash + "_section";
    if (window.location.hash !== "" && $(elemId).length) {
      headerHeight = $('header').height();
      offset = $(elemId).offset().top;
      return $("html, body").scrollTop(offset - headerHeight);
    }
  });
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sguha095/rk8y7/4/